# How to use .NET 6-windows and .NET 6 targets in one library

Tags: uno-platform

I've segregated my WinUI 3 application into different layers: Application, Infrastructure, Presentation etc.

And all the projects have targets: `net6.0-windows` and I want to move it to the Uno Platform.

So, I've added a new target: `net6.0`

And at this moment the problem arises:
Type [WinUI] component already defines a member, called `InitializeComponent` or some problems with binding.
[image]

Is it possible to make such type of library with targets to `net6-windows` and `net6.0`?

Answer (score 1):

For the Windows app project itself, you need to use `net6-windows`, as that provides additional dependencies specific to Windows app projects. All other libraries (non-app projects) can then use `net6.0`.

Regarding the specific error message, you are getting, the reason might be the generated files have some kind of conflict - you can try deleting the `obj` and `bin` folders and rebuild.

The easiest way to make existing Windows app support Uno would probably be to create a blank Uno solution and then migrate the code there (as the solution has already the required setup for platform-specific projects prepared and you can then just add your code.

Uno also provides [templates](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/src/SolutionTemplate/UnoLibraryTemplate.net6/CrossTargetedLibrary.csproj) for cross-targeted libraries, so you might be able to use similar approach. The one linked is for "UWP" solution however, so to make it WinUI, you would need to switch from `uap10.0.18362` to `net6-windows`.